# SpringNet load configuration file from environment variable?

Tags: c#, spring

I use C# and Spring Net 1.3.2 in console app.

I got  : 
an app.cfg
a spring-context.xml
a environnement.xml file wich contains specific variables values according to the where the app is running : a folder for production, one for qa, and one for test.

What I want to achieve : 
in my shell (windows), before launching the app with foo.bat, I do : 
set environment="qa"

When Spring loads the context, it picks the value contained in the environment var (say qa), and loads the correct file : thus replacing : configuration/{environment}/vars.xml

by configuration/qa/vars.xml.

In my my spring-context.xml file, I got objects like this : value = ${connectionString.DB1}" where the value is defined inside each vars.xml file (remember, one for prod, one for qa...).

For now, I am not able to replace the ${environment} variable. So I did it programmatically by getting the value of  ${environment} with  System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("environnement"); and using Path.Combine, load the two contexts myself  :

reader.LoadObjectDefinitions(envPath);
reader.LoadObjectDefinitions("configuration/common/springContext.xml");

BUT :
I would like to make it by configuration.
I've been playing with (with no luck) :

```
    <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.VariablePlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
      <property name="VariableSources">
        <list>
          <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.EnvironmentVariableSource, Spring.Core"/>
        </list>
      </property>
    </object>


   <object name="appConfigPropertyHolder"
            type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
       <property name="EnvironmentVariableMode" value="Override"/>
    </object>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after much research, it works!

```
<object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.VariablePlaceholderConfigurer, Spring.Core">
      <property name="VariableSources">
        <list>
          <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.EnvironmentVariableSource, Spring.Core"/>      
          <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.PropertyFileVariableSource, Spring.Core">
            <property name="Location" value="${root.config}/envars.properties" />
            <property name="IgnoreMissingResources" value="false"/>
          </object>
        </list>
      </property>
    </object>
```

path to property file depends upon the environment variable.
Variables are replaced by the values obtained from the properties file.

I deploy one package + folder with 4 environment properties files 
And I set my env var accordingly.
No need to mess with app.config or multiple Spring configuration files.